# how to evaluate this complex integral

Tags: complex-integration

$I=\int_{L} \frac{z}{\bar{z}}dz$, where L is $1\le|z|<2$, $Im(z)\ge 0$ traversed counterclockwise. 
thanks for helping.

$I=\int_{L} \frac{z}{\bar{z}}dz=\int_{L}{z^2\over |z|}dz$,

Comment: Is $L$ a specific contour? You specified a region in the complex plane, specifically half an annulus.

Comment: Yes L is a closed contour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$C_1:\,z=2e^{i\theta}~~;~~0\leq\theta\leq\pi$.

$C_2:\,z=t~~;~~-2\leq t\leq-1$.

$C_3:\,z=e^{i\theta}~~;~~0\leq\theta\leq\pi$.

$C_4:\,z=t~~;~~1\leq t\leq2$.
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_{L}\frac{z}{\bar{z}}dz\\
&=&\int_{C_1}+\int_{C_2}-\int_{-C_3}+\int_{C_4}\\
&=&\int_0^\pi e^{2i\theta}2ie^{i\theta}d\theta+\int_{-2}^{-1}dt-\int_0^\pi e^{2i\theta}ie^{i\theta}d\theta+\int_{1}^{2}dt\\
&=&\dfrac{-4}{3}+1-\dfrac{-2}{3}+1\\
&=&\dfrac{4}{3}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: the answer is $4/3$

Comment: @MyGlasses Why to make things so hard in $\;C_3\;$ ? Just parametrize $\;z=e^{i\theta}\;,\;\;0\le \theta\le\pi\;$, evaluate the integral and **then change the sign** !:$$\int_0^\pi\frac{e^{i\theta}}{e^{-i\theta}}ie^{i\theta}d\theta=\left.\frac13e^{3i\theta}\right|_0^\pi=-\frac23\pi$$ I think this way is easier and, it seems to me, there's a mistake in that integral.

Comment: @miosaki Sorry. Regard to very useful comment by DonAntonio I edited the solution.